# Use a variable to store a command line in perl/bash

Tags: perl, shell

I am trying to write a script (mix of perl and bash) to unzip files.

The unzip command is user-specific (depending on files), so the user needs to enter the beginning of the command, which is then store in a variable called $unzipCommand (perl). For example, the user could enter 'gunzip' or 'gunzip'. For example:

```
my $unzipCommand = "gunzip";
```

This variable is accessible and works, for example, I can print it to the screen. However, I want to use this to build a command line that I store in a .sh file.

I have tried various ways to do this, but nothing seems to work. 
Tha variable looks like this:

```
my $cmd = "$unzipCommand $path2zippedfile > $path2file";
```

And to store it in a shell script, I have tried:

```
`echo "$cmd" > $sh_script`;
```

and

```
open $sh_script, ">", "$QSUB" or die "Can't open '$QSUB'";
print $sh_script "$cmd";
close $sh_script;
```

It always seems that the command is 'executed' instead of printed in the file.

I know that the command works because if I hard code the 'gunzip', I don't get this error.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: turn on debugging to see what variables->values are visible during what level of quoting (dbl-quote vs back quotes, vs single quotes). Good luck.

Comment: What does `print "$cmd";` (Perl) give you?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code.

```
open ('FH','>',$sh) or die "unable to open $!\n";
my @arr = split(/' '/,$cmd);
foreach(@arr){ print FH $_;}
close(FH);
```

I am assuming that `$sh` is the script name and `$cmd` is the command which you want to write in script.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
open (FH, ">", "$sh_Script") or die "Can't open File Handle";
print FH "$cmd";
close FH;
```

I am assuming the `$sh_Script` is the path to your script which you want and `$cmd` is what you want to store in the file.

Comment: Yes, $sh_Script is the path and $cmd is the command (my bad). I tried this solution, but it didn't work :-(

Comment: What was the error ? Did it not print anything on the script ? Does the script file exists already ? if not create the file using something like this

`exec (touch $sh_Script) if (! -e $sh_Script);`

And then use my above answer after that.

Answer (score 0):

My contribution (full script) which takes hardcoded values and creates a little shell script with a single line.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;

my $unzipCommand = "gunzip";
my $path2zippedfile = "/home/honnor/zip1.gz";
my $unzipperScript = "unzipper.ksh";
my $cmd = "$unzipCommand $path2zippedfile";

print "$cmd";


open( my $fh, ">", $unzipperScript ) or die $!;
print $fh "$cmd";
close $fh;
```

Comment: Very similar to other answers on here - apologies :)